# iOS react-native not accept all unicodes of the font

Tags: ios, react-native, unicode, fonts

The icons of my React-Native app to be in a font `myIcons.ttf`, and i access this icons with characters unicode, like this:

`<Text fontSize='24' fontFamily='myIcons'>{'\u0041'}</Text>`

This work pretty in Android app, but in iOS some unicodes not are recognizes, that are: `\u007F` to `\u009F`. So this icons does not appear.

`<Text fontSize='24' fontFamily='myIcons'>{'\u0041'}</Text> // works on both
<Text fontSize='24' fontFamily='myIcons'>{'\u0086'}</Text> // not work in iOS`

I noticed that unicodes that have unrecognized iOS characters can not show them, so the icon does not appear.
`"\u0041"` -> `"A"` this unicode show the icon
`"\u0086"` -> `""` this unicode not show the icon

how i could make the iOS recognize all unicodes??